# R sum of vector multiplied by each row of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, sumproduct

I have a data frame `df` as follows:

```
    prod sd  c1   c2   c3
1   NA   NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
2   NA   NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
3   NA   NA 0.5 0.00 0.50
```

And a vector `v = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`.

For each row, I want to "sumproduct" `df$[,c(3:5)] * v` and put the result in `df$prod`, such that:

```
df$prod[1] <- (0.5 * 0.1) + (0.25 * 0.2) + (0.25 * 0.3)
df$prod[2] <- (0.5 * 0.1) + (0.5 * 0.2) + (0 * 0.3)
```

I've read a number of different threads about replicating Excels' sumproduct function, and tried a bunch of different things, but I haven't been able to come up with a working solution. Happy to detail what has not worked if that is helpful, but I suspect I am overlooking something very simple. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
transform(df, prod = rowSums(sweep(df[, 3:5], 2, v, `*`)))
```

Output:

```
   prod sd  c1   c2   c3
1 0.175 NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
2 0.150 NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
3 0.200 NA 0.5 0.00 0.50
```

Answer (score 5):

Using matrix multiplication:

```r
df$prod <- as.matrix(df[3:5]) %*% v
```

```
   prod sd  c1   c2   c3
1 0.175 NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
2 0.150 NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
3 0.200 NA 0.5 0.00 0.50
```

Reproducible data (please provide it yourself next time):

```
v <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

df <- read.csv(text =
"prod,sd,c1,c2,c3
NA,NA,0.5,0.25,0.25
NA,NA,0.5,0.50,0.00
NA,NA,0.5,0.00,0.50")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply`:

```
df$prod <- apply(df[,3:5], 1, function(x) sum(x*v))

df
   prod sd  c1   c2   c3
1 0.175 NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
2 0.150 NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
3 0.200 NA 0.5 0.00 0.50
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for pointing out the many ways to solve this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve it as follows:

```
df$prod <- colSums(t(df[, 3:5]) * v)

#    prod sd  c1   c2   c3
# 1 0.175 NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
# 2 0.150 NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
# 3 0.200 NA 0.5 0.00 0.50
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "    prod sd  c1   c2   c3
1   NA   NA 0.5 0.25 0.25
2   NA   NA 0.5 0.50 0.00
3   NA   NA 0.5 0.00 0.50", header=T)
```